# Solving equation over TruncatedDistribution (FindRoot)

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm trying to solve the following equation :

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Val1 = 0.4582;
Val2 = Sqrt[0.0052];
FindRoot[{
  Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{0.35, 0.7},NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]] == Val1,
  StandardDeviation[TruncatedDistribution[{0.35, 0.7}, NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]] == Val2},
{{mu, Val1}, {sig, Val2}}]
```

which gives :

```
(*{mu -> 0.412198, sig -> 0.102817}*)
```

So far so good but I'm wondering how long it takes mathematica to solve the system... Ideas to speed up the calculation? I don't need a very precise result, 5 decimal digits are enough.

ps : I have already tried several variations of WorkingPrecision, PrecisionGoal... it doesn't really speed up anything

Comment: On my comp your code is executed in 350.434 s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pre-calculate symbolic expressions for the mean and standard deviation of the truncated distribution:

```
ClearAll[mean, stdev]
mean[{a_, b_}, {mu_, sigma_}] = 
  Simplify[
    Mean@ TruncatedDistribution[{a, b}, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]], 
    0 < a < b
  ];

stdev[{a_, b_}, {mu_, sigma_}] = 
  Simplify[
    StandardDeviation@ TruncatedDistribution[{a, b}, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]], 
    0 < a < b
  ];
```

Note that, critically, these are defined with `Set` (`=`) and not `SetDelayed` (`:=`) so they are calculated once and then stored away for future use. These do take quite some time (a minute or two on my laptop), but then you get the nice bonus that you can change the truncation limits at will afterwards.

Once you have these, the `FindRoot` calculations becomes practically instantaneous:

```
Val1 = 0.4582;
Val2 = Sqrt[0.0052];

FindRoot[
  {mean[{0.35, 0.7}, {mu, sigma}] == Val1, 
   stdev[{0.35, 0.7}, {mu, sigma}] == Val2},
  {{mu, Val1}, {sigma, Val2}}
]

(* Out: {mu -> 0.412198, sigma -> 0.102817} *)
```

And you can easily change the truncation limits and the values at will, obtaining results very fast.

Comment: Your code is  faster ( 105 s s vs 192 s) without simplification.

Comment: @user64494 Good point, thank you! The simplification was there to remove a Piecewise conditional answer that I was worried might confuse FindRoot, but I guess its not really required.\

Answer (score 5):

Saving the truncated distribution's properties would allow for this calculation to proceed much more quickly.

However, asking *Mathematica* to directly calculate the standard deviation of the truncated distribution in the general case takes a distressingly long time itself. Doing some of this by hand results in a much faster solution, so:

Let us grab the PDF of the interior distribution and manually truncate it ourselves:

```
fpdf[mu_, sig_, x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sig], x];
```

And then calculate three related integrals where the limits are based on the truncation:

```
ex0 = Integrate[fpdf[mu, sig, x], {x, 35/100, 70/100}];
ex1 = Integrate[x fpdf[mu, sig, x], {x, 35/100, 70/100}]/ex0;
ex2 = Integrate[x^2 fpdf[mu, sig, x], {x, 35/100, 70/100}]/ex0;
```

`ex0` captures the amount of normal distribution within the truncated region, `ex1` captures the expected value of a variable sampled from the normal distribution, and `ex2` capture $E(X^2)$. These three integrals take about 6 seconds total to evaluate on my machine.

From [an answer over on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/636096), we can see that with this information we can calculate the mean and variance directly:

```
distMean[mu_, sig_] = ex1;
distVariance[mu_, sig_] = ex2 - ex1^2;
```

And relatedly, the standard deviation:

```
distStdDev[mu_, sig_] = Sqrt[ex2 - ex1^2];
```

If we plug in these `distMean` and `distStdDev` functions into the original `FindRoot`, we find that the solution is quite fast:

```
FindRoot[{distMean[mu, sig] == 0.4582, 
  distStdDev[mu, sig] == Sqrt[0.0052]}, {{mu, 0.5}, {sig, 0.1}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002852, {mu -> 0.412198, sig -> 0.102817}}

This approach can potentially be generalized to other types of distributions, but it is somewhat dependent on being able to get a nice closed form for the 3 integrals involved for maximum speedup.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to estimate the parameters using the "method of moments" rather than using maximum likelihood.  (If not, then you should consider maximum likelihood as it computes much faster and you can also easily obtain estimates of precision.)

```
(* Generate some data *)
d = TruncatedDistribution[{0.35, 0.7}, NormalDistribution[mu, sig]];
d2 = d /. mu -> 0.4 /. sig -> 0.1
SeedRandom[12345];
x = RandomVariate[d2, 1000];

(* Method of moments *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 FindDistributionParameters[x, d, {{mu, 0.4}, {sig, 0.1}},
  ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]]
(* {11.81 seconds, {mu -> 0.379214, sig -> 0.112361}} *)

(* Maximum likelihood *)
AbsoluteTiming[FindDistributionParameters[x, d, {{mu, 0.4}, {sig, 0.1}}]]
(* {0.37837 seconds, {mu -> 0.379214, sig -> 0.112361}} *)
```

For this particular sample the two sets of estimates match.  However, that is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach is as follows. Its advantage is that you find `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` only one time.

```
a = Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{7/20, 7/10},NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{4.8678, -((E^(-(49/(200 sig^2)) - mu^2/( 2 sig^2)) (-Sqrt[2] E^(147/(800 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(20 sig^2)) sig Abs[7 - 20 mu] Abs[7 - 10 mu] +  Sqrt[2] E^((7 mu)/(10 sig^2)) sig Abs[7 - 20 mu] Abs[7 - 10 mu] +  7 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[7 - 10 mu] Erf[Abs[7 - 20 mu]/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  20 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[7 - 10 mu] Erf[Abs[7 - 20 mu]/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  7 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[7 - 20 mu] Erf[Abs[7 - 10 mu]/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  10 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[7 - 20 mu] Erf[Abs[7 - 10 mu]/( 10 Sqrt[2] sig)]))/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[7 - 20 mu] Abs[ 7 - 10 mu] (-Erf[(-(7/10) + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sig)] +  Erf[(-(7/20) + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sig)])))}`

```
b = StandardDeviation[TruncatedDistribution[{7/20, 7/10}, NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{96.9828, (1/( 2^(3/4) Sqrt[ 5 \[Pi]]))(\[Sqrt](-((E^(-(49/(100 sig^2)) - mu^2/sig^2) sig (Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)]) (-20 Sqrt[2] E^( 147/(400 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(10 sig^2)) sig +  40 Sqrt[2] E^(147/(800 sig^2) + (21 mu)/(20 sig^2)) sig -  20 Sqrt[2] E^((7 mu)/(5 sig^2)) sig -  7 E^(343/(800 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(20 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  14 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(10 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  20 E^(343/(800 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(20 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  20 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(10 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/(20 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  10 Sqrt[2] E^( 49/(100 sig^2) + mu^2/sig^2) \[Pi] sig Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/( 20 Sqrt[2] sig)]^2 +  7 E^(343/(800 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(20 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  14 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(10 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  20 E^(343/(800 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(20 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  20 E^(49/(200 sig^2) + (7 mu)/(10 sig^2) + mu^2/(2 sig^2)) mu Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] -  20 Sqrt[2] E^( 49/(100 sig^2) + mu^2/sig^2) \[Pi] sig Erf[(7 - 20 mu)/( 20 Sqrt[2] sig)] Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/(10 Sqrt[2] sig)] +  10 Sqrt[2] E^( 49/(100 sig^2) + mu^2/sig^2) \[Pi] sig Erf[(7 - 10 mu)/( 10 Sqrt[2] sig)]^2))/((Erf[(-(7/10) + mu)/( Sqrt[2] sig)] -  Erf[(-(7/20) + mu)/( Sqrt[2] sig)])^2 (-Erf[(-(7/10) + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sig)] +  Erf[(-(7/20) + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sig)])))))}`

Now

```
Val1 = 0.4582;Val2 = Sqrt[0.0052];
FindRoot[{a[[2]] == Val1,  b[[2]] == Val2}, {{mu, Val1}, {sig, Val2}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.0036685, {mu -> 0.412198, sig -> 0.102817}}`

For comparison, I could not execute your code during several minutes.

Comment: For comparison, the @MarcoB's code  `mean[{a_, b_}, {mu_, sigma_}] = 
 Simplify[Mean@
    TruncatedDistribution[{a, b}, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]], 
   0 < a < b] // AbsoluteTiming`  results in `{56.7278, ((-E^(-((a - mu)^2/(2 sigma^2))) + 
     E^(-((b - mu)^2/(2 sigma^2)))) Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] sigma + 
  mu Erf[(a - mu)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)] - 
  mu Erf[(b - mu)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)])/(
 Erfc[(-a + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)] - Erfc[(-b + mu)/(Sqrt[2] sigma)])` on my comp.

Comment: For comparison,  on my comp the @MarcoB command `stdev[{a_, b_}, {mu_, sigma_}] = 
 Simplify[StandardDeviation@
    TruncatedDistribution[{a, b}, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]], 
   0 < a < b] // AbsoluteTiming`  takes 135.681 s.

Comment: For comparison. on my comp `Clear[...]; 
Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{low, upper}, 
   NormalDistribution[mu, sig]]] // AbsoluteTiming` takes 29.9502 s.